# Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null

Tags: php, slim

I have a error saying that,

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null on line 63
```

but how can i check the element, here is my code

```
54 public function edit($id) {
55  $form_group = $this->dm->find(Form_Group::class, $id);
56  if (empty($form_group)) {
57      $this->app->flash('error', 'Invalid record selected.');
58      $this->app->redirect($this->app->urlFor('form-group-list'));
59      die;
60  }
61
62  $record_company = $form_group->getCompany();
63  $enabled_modules = Common_Helper::get_enabled_modules($record_company->getId());
```

Comment: var_dump `$record_company` to see what is in there

Comment: `$form_group->getCompany();` is returning null, can we see the code for that

Answer (score -3):

The problem is in this line:

```
$record_company = $form_group->getCompany(); // it returns null
```

You have to var_dump the $form_group variable and check content to be sure.

But as I can see, the form group doesn't have a company.

Comment: I would var_dump $form_group, $record_company will dump null anyway